# Undefined nameToPath when using ClojureScript's :npm-deps

Tags: npm, clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm trying to install the [Ant Design](https://ant.design) library via `:npm-deps`, so in my project.clj I have:

```
  :cljsbuild {:builds {:app
                       {:source-paths ["src" "env/dev/cljs"]
                        :compiler
                        {:main "metro-parks-cljs-components.dev"
                         :output-to "public/js/app.js"
                         :output-dir "public/js/out"
                         :asset-path   "js/out"
                         :source-map true
                         :optimizations :none
                         :install-deps true
                         :npm-deps {:react "^16.8.5"
                                    :react-dom "^16.8.5"
                                    :antd "^3.15.2"
                                    :moment "^2.24.0"}}
                         ...
```

And in my app code:

```
(ns metro-parks-cljs-components.event-finder
  (:require
    ...
    [reagent.core :as r]
    [moment]
    [antd :refer [DatePicker Pagination]]))
```

This compiles but on page load I get:

```
Error: Undefined nameToPath for module$home$ctamayo$workspace$metro_parks$wp_content$themes$metro_parks$metro_parks_cljs_components$node_modules$antd$es$affix base.js:1357:21
    visitNode http://localhost:3449/js/out/goog/base.js:1357
    visitNode http://localhost:3449/js/out/goog/base.js:1355
    visitNode http://localhost:3449/js/out/goog/base.js:1355
    visitNode http://localhost:3449/js/out/goog/base.js:1355
    writeScripts_ http://localhost:3449/js/out/goog/base.js:1369
    require http://localhost:3449/js/out/goog/base.js:706
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3449/index.html:80
```

**Is this a known issue with `npm-deps` right now? Is there a workaround?**

Note: I have looked into using shadow-cljs but I'm hesitant to migrate to a whole new build system due to time constraints.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?... I'm having +1 moment. Thx!

Comment: @jbg no, I did end up using [shadow-cljs](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_using_npm_packages). I'd recommend going that route if you need to interact with the NPM ecosystem at all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I ended up doing exactly that: switching to shadow-cljs.